# Firebase Messaging shouldEstablishDirectChannel not establishing connection on first app launch

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

#### Problem

When launching an app for the first time, or after deleting and re-installing, `Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel` does not establish the socket connection.  If I shut down the app, and re-open it, then the socket connection is established.

Steps to reproduce:

1)  Place this code in AppDelegate:

`FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true`

2)  Place this code anywhere after to check if connection is established:
`Messaging.messaging().isDirectChannelEstablished` 
This always returns false.

3) Listen for connection state change and observe that this notification never gets fired.

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(fcmConnectionStateChange), name:
            NSNotification.Name.MessagingConnectionStateChanged, object: nil)`

That is the problem in a nutshell.  If I simply kill the app, and re-launch it, everything works as expected.  The socket connection is made and the `MessagingConnectionStateChanged` notification is fired.

Why is `Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel` not connecting on my initial app launch?

Relevant Code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.rootViewController = RootViewController.shared
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        setUpFirebase()
        setUpPushNotificationsForApplication(application)
        RootViewController.shared.goToLoginVC()

        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Firebase

    func setUpFirebase() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(fcmConnectionStateChange), name:
            NSNotification.Name.MessagingConnectionStateChanged, object: nil)        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    }

    // MARK: - Firebase Notifications

    func fcmConnectionStateChange() {
       // This is never called on app's first launch!!!
        print(Messaging.messaging().isDirectChannelEstablished)
    }
```

#### Environment

- Xcode version: 8.3.3
- Firebase 4.1.0
- FirebaseAnalytics 4.0.3
- FirebaseCore 4.0.5
- FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.1
- FirebaseMessaging 2.0.1
- Firebase Product: Messaging

Answer (score 2):

FCM connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

I modified your code, try this.

```
func setUpFirebase() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
        #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: 
        NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
        #selector(self.fcmConnectionStateChange), name:
        NSNotification.Name.MessagingConnectionStateChanged, object: nil)        
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
}

func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard InstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        return;
    }
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

func fcmConnectionStateChange() {
    if Messaging.messaging().isDirectChannelEstablished {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
    } else {
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Add this before using NotificationCenter.

```
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        print("iOS 10 up")
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("regist fail = \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            if granted {
                print("allow regist")
            } else {
                //Handle user denying permissions..
                print("deny regist")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("iOS 9 down")
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings( pushNotificationSettings )
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: fcmConnectionStateChange still not firing, even when instancID token and fcmToken are not nil.

Comment: After my test, maybe you should get notification permission first.